# Pattern matching with generic arguments in C#

Tags: c#, generics, pattern-matching

In C# I've a situation like this:

```
class ModelBase<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}

class Repo<TModel, TKey> :
    where TModel : ModelBase<TKey>
{
    //code where I access both TModel and TKey types
}
```

In my Repo class, I need to access both the `TModel` and `TKey`, but when I specific the `TModel` argument, a pattern matching system should be able to extract the `TKey` automatically.

For use the `TKey` generic type, I have to declare it as a generic argument, so every time that I need to create a Repo, I have to specific model and relative key types. How could I remove the need of explicit the key type, and extract it by pattern matching? A solution that uses verification at compile time is preferred.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't. You must include all generic types. Most likely in your `Repo`, you're going to have a method to retrieve your `ModelBase` object by it's ID. In that case, you'll need the `TKey` type as a parameter anyway. It's annoying to type, and would be _nice_ if they could infer it from the first generic parameter, but here we are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a workaround for this might be declaring a non-generic type with a single property to store the primary key type. Then the generic type could inherit from that and set the property in the constructor.

Something like this:

```
class ModelBase
{
    public Type KeyType { get; set; }
}

class ModelBase<TKey> : ModelBase
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }

    public ModelBase()
    {
        KeyType = typeof(TKey);
    }
}

class Repo<TModel> where TModel : ModelBase, new()
{
    // code where I access both TModel and TKey types
    public void Test()
    {
        var modelType = typeof(TModel).Name;
        var keyType = new TModel().KeyType.Name;
        Console.WriteLine($"{modelType}     {keyType}");
    }
}
```

Would allow you to write code like this:

```
class MyIntEntity : ModelBase<int>
{
    public new int Id { get; set; }
}

class MyStringEntity : ModelBase<string>
{
    public new string Id { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var repoIntegerKey = new Repo<MyIntEntity>();
        var repoStringKey = new Repo<MyStringEntity>();

        repoIntegerKey.Test(); // prints "MyIntEntity        Int32"
        repoStringKey.Test();  // prints "MyStringEntity     String"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }        
}
```

Comment: This only enables you to access an *instance* of `Type` representing the type of the generic type argument `TKey`. That is *very different* to accessing the generic type argument itself. If knowing the type is enough then this works.

Comment: This would only work in extreme edge cases. For the vast majority of cases, you will want to state the type so that you can utilize that property.

Comment: Also, this will not compile as is, and you'll have to use the `new` keyword on the `Id` properties when you declare your subtypes. This "overwriting" of subclass properties should help point out that what you're doing is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is not possible in C# due to two reasons:

1. There is no type inference in constructors:

   ```
   class Foo<T>
   { 
       public Foo(T t) { ... }
   }

   var foo = new Foo(1); //compile time error, `int` will not be inferred
   ```

   This limitation is strange and not coherent at all with how method type inference works. Constructors are not methods but this *should* be possible.
2. Type inference is either all or none, no middle ground:

   ```
   T Whatever<T, Q>(Q q) where Q: T { ... }
   ```

   Partial type inference in whatever hypothetical syntax you might think simply does not work:

   ```
   var blah = NewFoo<Blah>(q); //compile time error
   ```

   Or

   ```
   var blah = NewFoo<Blah,>(q); //compile time error
   ```

   will simply fail.

Why? Well, because the language is designed the way it is. The first limitation could be resolved, the second one I don't see it happening any time soon so take a seat if you plan to wait for it.